# Change a Webpart based on Geo-Location

Tags: web-part

Im curious if the following exists, and if anyone out there has developed this and might be able to point me in the direction of a tutorial that could help me do what Im about to describe...

At work, on my SharePoint site I have a webpart that has weather streaming in from an RSS Feed. What I would like to do is develop a webpart that picks  up on the user's geographic location and changes the weather the user see's based on the geographic location, so:

Bob is in Denver, so when he accesses the site he will see weather for Denver
Joe is in Houston, so when he access the site, he will see the weather for Houston.

Has anyone out there done this? If so where would be a good place to get started? Ive developed Webparts before, but nothing like this. I know its possible (Ive seen it at other companies), and Im finally ready to attempt making one myself :). Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I've done something where I check the user's IP address (Remote_address) and choose what content to display in a DVWP. This required me to have some knowledge of our internal network and what subnets pointed to what regions so I could separate content properly.

There are third party services like MaxMInd that will get you IP address mapping that you could evaluate against and in turn point to different content.

Alternatively, if your user profiles have city/state information, you should be able to access the curent logged in user's profile and user that to then pass to a weather API service to get the proper data.

Answer (score 0):

You can't exactly get user's location however what you can do is [create a webpart with custom properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and then in CreateChildControls method or [render method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25019/Developing-SharePoint-WebParts) then get user's IP address as described in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735350/how-to-get-a-users-client-ip-address-in-asp-net) which can be used to get his [Approx location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327629/get-user-location-by-ip-address).

Once you got location you can use any API out of hundreds out there to get weather information for example [Google's weather API](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/153911-c#using-google-weather-api-in-a-c#-application/).

Answer (score 0):

Couple of months ago, we did a web part to show the current location of the logged in user in our intranet. Our approach was Getting his/her location from Active Directory using the **IP** address. If your users are part of your company and part of the active directory, you can use this approach. As PirateEric already mentioned in his answer, it is using the current network **IP** and getting the **subnet** value pointing to the region.

There are many vendors who provide us APIs to find the IP location of the users. I do use IP Location.net http://www.iplocation.net/ to find the location of my site visitors. Make use of such tools to get Geo location of your users and process the request accordingly.